# Trying to sort character variable into new variable with new value based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, case, mutate

I want to sort a character variable into two categories in a new variable based on conditions, in conditions are not met i want it to return "other".

If variable x cointains 4 character values "A", "B", "C" & "D" I want   to sort them into a 2 categories,    1 and 0, in a new variable y, creating a dummy variable

Ideally I want it to look like this

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C" & "D")

 y <- if x == "A" | "D" then assign 1 in y
 if x == "B" | "C" then assign 0 in y
 if x == other then assign NA in y

    x   y
  1 "A"  1
  2 "B"  0
  3 "C"  0
  4 "D"  1



 library(dplyr)
 df <- df %>% mutate ( y =case_when(
  (x %in% df == "A" | "D") ~ 1 , 
  (x %in% df == "B" | "C") ~ 1,
   x %in% df ==  ~ NA
 ))
```

I got this error message

```
Error: replacement has 3 rows, data has 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the proper `case_when` syntax.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
 
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(y = case_when(x %in% c("A", "D") ~ 1,
                       x %in% c("B", "C") ~ 0,
                       TRUE ~ NA_real_))
df
#>   x y
#> 1 A 1
#> 2 B 0
#> 3 C 0
#> 4 D 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're combining syntaxes in a way that makes sense in speech but not in code.
Generally you can't use `foo == "G" | "H"`. You need to use `foo == "G" | foo == "H"`, or the handy shorthand `foo %in% c("G", "H")`.

Similarly `x %in% df == "A"` doesn't make sense `x %in% df` makes sense. `df == "A"` makes sense. Putting them together `x %in% df == ...` does not make sense to R. (Okay, it does make sense to R, but not the same sense it does to you. R will use its Order of Operations which evaluates  `x %in% df` first and gets a `result` from that, and then checks whether that `result == "A"`, which is not what you want.)

Inside a `dplyr` function like `mutate`, you don't need to keep specifying `df`. You pipe in `df` and now you just need to use the column `x`. `x %in% df` looks like you're testing whether the column `x` is in the data frame `df`, which you don't need to do. Instead use `x %in% c("A", "D")`. Aron's answer shows the full correct syntax, I hope this answer helps you understand why.